# ANDROID sendBroadcast to UNITY BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android project, and i've stumbled on a little problem. I made a rolling ball game from the unity tutorial page, and now i want to send the controls from an android application. This is crucial, i don't want the game to intercept the controls itself. I was using this tutorial:

http://jeanmeyblum.weebly.com/scripts--tutorials/communication-between-an-android-app-and-unity

I made a service in the android application, which i think is quite OK. I tested it if it's running in the debugger, and it is. Then i made the receiver according to the instruction, the same with the plugin part. When i run the game (which is in an activity in the android application), the receiver is ALMOST working, he gets the "text" value that i set in the static variable, but only the value that was in the declaration at the beginning (so i think that the plugin part is working correctly).
The problem is that the onReceive() method is not being called, thus the "text" value wont change to "-1" which would move the ball in the opposite direction (the ball is always moving in the +1 direction).

Here is the code:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static MyReceiver instance;
    // text that will be read by Unity
    public static String text = "1";
    // Triggered when an Intent is catched
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // We get the data the Intent has
        String sentIntent = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        //if (sentIntent != null) {
            text = "-1";
        //}
    }
    public static void createInstance()
    {
        if(instance ==  null)
        {
            instance = new MyReceiver();
        }   
    }
}
```

And the Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int numIntent = 0;

    // It's the code we want our Handler to execute to send data
    private Runnable sendData = new Runnable() {
        // the specific method which will be executed by the handler
        public void run() {
            numIntent++;

            // sendIntent is the object that will be broadcast outside our app
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();

            // We add flags for example to work from background         
            sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION|Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND|Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES  );

            // SetAction uses a string which is an important name as it identifies the sender of the intent and that we will give to the receiver to know what to listen.
            // By convention, it's suggested to use the current package name
            sendIntent.setAction("com.example.package");

            // Here we fill the Intent with our data, here just a string with an incremented number in it.
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "1000");
            // And here it goes ! our message is send to any other app that want to listen to it.
            sendBroadcast(sendIntent);

            // In our case we run this method each second with postDelayed
            handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    // When service is started
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        // We first start the Handler
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendData);
        handler.postDelayed(sendData, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

I also edited the manifests:

```
<service
        android:name="com.example.MyService"
        android:enabled="true" >
        </service>
```

and the receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.receiver.MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.package">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I can see the MyService in the phones settings, and the game gets the declared "text" value. The problem is the onReceive method i thin, which is never even called. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I left this project for some time, and came back to it yesterday. AND I MADE IT. The problem was that the UNITY receiver had to be also registered in the ANDROID manifest, in fact i think it has to be registered in both of the manifests. I hope this helps someone someday :D

Comment: I tried registering receiver in both the manifest files ie in Unity and in JAR. But still not getting onReceive() called. :(
Can you guide me with some more details please?

Comment: +1 for answer and question too.. hey thanx alot.. It did work for me too. The thing is u jst need to register receiver as with full package name in both the Manifest file.
<receiver android:name="com.test.app.PluginBroadcastReceiver">
Like this.

Comment: Hi, I m stuck in same issue. I tried to register receiver in both manifest file i.e. in unity and in jar. But I m still not getting onReceive() called. Can you please guide.